# Beamer's ToCs displaying/hidding subsections not at the same vertical position

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, vertical-alignment, positioning

`Beamer`'s frames with the `t` option are supposed:

- to be vertically aligned at the top,
- hence to display their first lines at the same vertical position.

Nevertheless, this is not the case for frames containing tables of contents, depending on these ToCs display subsections or not, as pointed out by the following MCE.

Do you see what's going on?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1 of section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2 of section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 1 of section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2 of section 2}
\begin{frame}[t]
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
  \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While `[t]` configures the frame to be top-aligned, `\tableofcontents` adds some spacing on its own. It distributes the space between the sections in the normal case and sets `1.5em` of space between sections for `hideallsections`. This is hardcoded in `beamerbasetoc.sty` in the `\beamer@sectionintoc` macro: The important part is

```
        \ifx\beamer@toc@ooss\beamer@hidetext
          \vskip1.5em
        \else
          \vfill
        \fi
```

You could add `\vspace{0pt plus 1filll}` at the bottom of the `\tableofcontents` frames to force them into top-alignment, but then the normal `\tableofcontents` start higher than the `\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]` and there is no spacing between the sections for the first command, so it does not look great.

If you only care about aligning the first lines, you can add `\vspace{1.5em plus -1fill}` before `\tableofcontents` to align them:
[image]

Comment: Interesting! Where are these precise dimensions coming from? Unfortunately, your last trick leads to a huge vertical space between the two sections displayed by `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: Investigating a bit, it turns out that replacing the `\vfill` by `\vskip1.5em` in `\beamer@sectionintoc` gives the expected result. I wonder if it should be the case when the the underlying frame has `t` option.

Comment: While this leads to reasonable spacing, it leaves the `1.5em` vertical offset in contrast to "normal" `[t]` frames, so if you do this it would probably be reasonable to add a negative `1.5em` space before the TOC to fix this.

Comment: Indeed but, surprisingly enough, a negative space before the TOC of `1.5em` is too much while of `1em` is okay.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of setting `tocdepth` manually and a top-aligned minipage seems to align the TOCs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1 of section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2 of section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 1 of section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2 of section 2}

\begin{frame}[t]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
  \tableofcontents
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{frame}[t]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
  \tableofcontents
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Indeed, but would be nice to keep the `\tableofcontents`' optional argument provided by `beamer` and to not have to manually enter `minipage`s.